# When not to close response body

Tags: go

golang requires the response body of an http request be closed in user code, to free resources:

```
client := http.DefaultClient
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

My question is: why is this the design? Are there situations where not closing is beneficial? Why does the standard library not close the connection within `client.Do(req)` for the user?

I ask because this is a gotcha I see fairly frequently reviewing code.

Comment: On top of the answers posted, a request may be to an [SSE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) which does not terminate. As such you want to be able to continuously read the body & will never close the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no size limit to the content you receive from the server. You may be downloading a very large file. That's why the response contains a reader: so you can stream the response.

Since you can stream the response, you have to close the stream when you are done, or when you are not interested in the rest of the results. When you close the stream, the server will know that you are no longer interested in receiving the rest of the stream, and it will have a chance to clean up.

Comment: Thanks - it was not clear to me after client.Do(req) returns, bytes may still be sent over the wire and filling up the reader.

Comment: @Burak Serdar: Not meaning to be invasive, but could you share your thoughts on this please. Any useful guidance even a comment would be totally appreciated - https://stackoverflow.com/q/75878447/5291015. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Reason for closing the reader is already explained in @Burak Serdar 's answer.

> Are there situations where not closing is beneficial?. Why does the standard library not close the connection within client.Do(req) for the user?

Could be beneficial if you need to create a custom client that wraps Do() while returning a reader that isn't closed.

A simple example:

```golang
func main() {
    myCustomClient := CustomClient{
        client: http.Client{},
    }
    req,_ := http.NewRequest("GET", "example.com", nil)
    res, _ := myCustomClient.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    // (2) so you can read from it here

}

type CustomClient struct {
    client http.Client
}

func (c CustomClient)Do(req *http.Request)(*http.Response, error){
    // you may add some custom logic here, such as adding some headers
    // (1) and return the response without closing it 
    return c.client.Do(req)
}
```